# Checking if a string contains a username from a database to make a message green

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a list of username from a database to see if a message contains @username, and right now I have this code:

```
if (strpos($data[3], '@') !== false) {
    $user_array_thing = array();
    $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users");
    while($user_username = mysql_fetch_array($user_query) && in_array($data[4],$user_array_thing) === false){
        if(strpos($data[3],'@'.$user_username['username']) !== false){
            //echo a message to somebody
            echo '<li class="qn"><a href="/status/index.php?user='.$prof_user.'&status='.$data[4].'" class="qn_vis"><font color="#007a00"><b><< '.$data[2].':</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$data[3].'</font> - <font size="1" color="#a3a3a3">'.Timesince(strtotime($time)).' ago</font></a></a><!--<div id="delete'.$data[4].'" style="display:none; margin:0px;" class="qn_div"><form method="post" action=""><input type="hidden" name="messageid" id="messageid" value="'.$data[4].'" /><input class="button small red" type="submit" id="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" /></form><br></div>-->';
            $user_array_thing[] = $data[4];
        }
    }
} else { 
    $data[3] = preg_replace('|\B#([\d\w_]+)|i', '<font color="#8020E0">$0</font>', $data[3]);
    $data[3] = preg_replace('|\B\@([\d\w_]+)|i', '<font color="#1378E0">$0</font>', $data[3]);
    echo '<li class="qn"><a href="/status/index.php?user='.$prof_user.'&status='.$data[4].'" class="qn_vis"><img src="/images/icons/web/Bubble3.png" /><font color="#147CE6"><b>'.$data[2].' said</font>:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$data[3].'<font size="1" color="#a3a3a3"> - '.$commentcount.''.Timesince(strtotime($time)).' ago</font></a></a>';
}
```

It works perfectly, until you post something with an e-mail address in it, like 'someone@gmail.com'

gmail.com is not in the database, but is still turning green. I'm not sure what I've done wrong, I've been trying to fix this for days now, to no avail. Any suggestions would be nice

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Unrelated suggestion, but use semantic markup rather than explicitly setting a font color inline. Use CSS classes, but more than that, CSS classes that describe the meaning of the element on the page.  For example, use "user-message-highlight" instead of directly setting the color to green and "message-submit-button" instead of "button small red". It makes it easier to maintain your thematic elements since it's all in your CSS and easier to understand what the intent of the mark up is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the database to do this work for you?

```
<?php
$username = mysql_real_escape_string ($data['username']); // or wherever you're getting the username from 
$query    = mysql_query ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    // that username sure does exist in the database!
}
else {
    // poo!
}
```

Also note that `ext/mysql` is officially deprecated (as of PHP 5.5.0) and should not be used. You are advised to use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) for connecting to MySQL.

Hope this helps